# Dlang - Understaning std.cycle() in assembly

Tags: assembly, std, d, x86-64, abi

```d
import std.range : cycle;
void foo() pure @safe {
    cycle([1, 2]);
}
```

Today i encountered a program written in the D language.  I'm trying to understand its assembly code, starting with a simple function.

From [the asm output on the D compiler explorer](http://asm.dlang.org/#compilers:!((compiler:dmd2071,options:'',source:'import+std.range+:+cycle%3B%0Avoid+foo()+pure+@safe+%7B%0A%09cycle(%5B1,+2%5D)%3B%0A%7D')),filterAsm:(binary:!t,intel:!t),version:3):

```d
pure nothrow @nogc @safe std.range.Cycle!(int[]).Cycle std.range.cycle!(int[]).cycle(int[]):
 push   rbp
 mov    rbp,rsp
 sub    rsp,0x40
 mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x20],rdi
 mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x10],rsi
 mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],rdx
 ... rest of the function
```

I've tried to read it serveral time, but can't understanding why 
`std.range.cycle()` gets 3 arguments (`RDI`, `RSI` and `RDX`), or where my range is (`[1, 2]`).  It's not a C-like structure?

Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you're using the x86-64 SystemV ABI, based on rdi and rsi for arg passing, since the Windows 64-bit ABI uses different regs.  See the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki for links to ABI docs, or see [the current revision here](https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/x86-64-psABI-r252.pdf).

Small objects (like structs) passed by value go in multiple integer registers.  Returning large objects (more than 128 bits) by value also uses a hidden pointer to space allocated by the caller, instead of packing into RDX:RAX.  This is what happens in your function.

Based on the asm and [docs](http://dlang.org/library/std/range/cycle.html), I think a Cycle object has three values: start, end, and index.  I don't know D at all, but it would make sense.  Since they're all 64-bit, that makes it too large to fit in RDX:RAX, so it's returned by hidden pointer.

**The arg-passing registers on entry to Cycle() are**:

- RDI: "hidden" pointer to the return value (which is a struct of three 64-bit integers)
- RSI: first member of the Range arg (I'll call it range_start)
- RDX: second member of the Range arg (I'll call it range_end)

---

I enabled optimization to get more readable asm without so much noise, but it looks like this D compiler is a lot less sophisticated than clang or gcc, unfortunately.  With [`-O -release -inline`](http://asm.dlang.org/#compilers:!((compiler:dmd2071,options:'-O+-release+-inline',source:'import+std.range+:+cycle%3B%0Avoid+foo()+pure+@safe+%7B%0A%09cycle(%5B1,+2%5D)%3B%0A%7D')),filterAsm:(binary:!t,intel:!t),version:3) (as recommended by [this page](https://dlang.org/dmd-linux.html)), it still does a *lot* of store/reload to the stack.

```
pure nothrow @nogc @safe std.range.Cycle!(int[]).Cycle std.range.cycle!(int[]).cycle(int[]):
 sub    rsp,0x28
 mov    QWORD PTR [rsp+0x20],rdi        # hidden first arg (return-value pointer).
 mov    QWORD PTR [rsp+0x8],0x0         # totally useless: overwritten without read

 mov    QWORD PTR [rsp+0x10],0x0        # totally useless: same.

 mov    QWORD PTR [rsp+0x8],rsi         # first "real" arg
 mov    QWORD PTR [rsp+0x10],rdx        # second "real" arg
 xor    eax,eax
 xor    edx,edx                         # zero rax:rdx.  Perhaps from the index=0 default when you only use one arg?
 div    QWORD PTR [rsp+0x8]             # divide 0 by first arg of the range.
 mov    QWORD PTR [rsp+0x18],rdx        # remainder of (index / range_start), I guess.
 lea    rsi,[rsp+0x8]                   # RSI=pointer to where range_start, range_end, and index/range_start were stored on the stack.
 movs   QWORD PTR es:[rdi],QWORD PTR ds:[rsi]  # copy to the dst buffer.  A smart compiler would have stored there in the first place, instead of to local scratch and then copying.
 movs   QWORD PTR es:[rdi],QWORD PTR ds:[rsi]  # movs is not very efficient, this is horrible code.
 movs   QWORD PTR es:[rdi],QWORD PTR ds:[rsi]
 mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rsp+0x20]        # mov rax, rdi  before those MOVS instructions would have been much more efficient.
 add    rsp,0x28
 ret
```

The ABI requires functions that return large objects to return the hidden pointer in RAX, so the caller doesn't have to separately keep a copy of the pointer to the return buffer.  That's why the function sets RAX at all.

---

**A good compiler would have done this**:

```
std.range.Cycle...:
   mov    [rdi], rsi           # cycle_start
   mov    [rdi+0x8], rdx       # cycle_end
   mov    [rdi+0x10], 0        # index
   mov    rax, rdi
   ret
```

Or just inlined the call to Cycle entirely, since it's trivial.  Actually, I think it *did* inline into foo(), but a stand-alone definition for cycle() is still emitted.

We can't tell which two functions `foo()` calls, because the compiler explorer seems to be disassembling the .o (not the linked binary) without resolving symbols.  So the call offset is `00 00 00 00`, a placeholder for the linker.  But it's probably calling a memory allocation function, because it makes the call with esi=2 and edi=0.  ([Using `mov edi, 0` in optimizing release mode!  Yuck!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666617/what-is-the-best-way-to-set-a-register-to-zero-in-x86-assembly-xor-mov-or-and)).  The call target shows as the next instruction, because that's where [call's rel32 displacement](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CALL.html) counts from.

Hopefully [LDC](https://github.com/ldc-developers/ldc#installation) or [GDC](https://gdcproject.org/downloads) do a better job, since they're based on modern optimizing backends (LLVM and gcc), but the compiler-explorer site you linked doesn't have those compilers installed.  If there's another site based on [Matt Godbolt's compiler explorer code](http://gcc.godbolt.org/), but with other D compilers, that would be cool.

Comment: DLang docs also discuss how objects, arrays etc in general work and their relationship to the underlying ABI. I only present the link as an additional source of information that might be valuable if you are dealing with other aspects of DLang. https://dlang.org/spec/abi.html . The docs use the Windows 32-bit x86 ABI with examples, but you apply the information to whatever the ABI specs are for the target host.

Comment: You might try [LDC](https://github.com/ldc-developers/ldc#installation) or [GDC](https://gdcproject.org/downloads) which use the LLVM and GCC backends for code generation, respectively. DMD uses the Digital Mars backend which traces its lineage all the way back to Zortech C++ (the first C++ compiler that generated object code rather than just transpiling to C) so it's not exactly cutting edge.

Comment: @eco: Thanks, I'm relieved to hear that there are D compilers that use advanced back-ends.  That makes learning D much more appealing, although honestly I think Rust is next on my list of languages to learn.  I think its approach to integer overflow ([i32.wrapping_add(value), or i32.checked_add(value)](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i32.html)) is neat, and so is building things like popcnt into the language, instead of requiring portable code to use some idiom that the compiler can recognize and compile back into a good popcnt implementation for the target instruction set.

Comment: @PeterCordes http://d.godbolt.org/

And yeah, Rust is next on my list as well. A lot of cool stuff going on there.